# Cloudinary: Any way to remove padding of user photos?

Tags: cloudinary

Is it possible somehow with `Cloudinary` to remove this kind of photo paddings? Or is it any image cloud storage offers this functionality? Read though [docs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformation_reference), but not find any similar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e_trim` to achieve this:
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/e_trim/https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbNKD.jpg

You can read more about it here:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformation_reference#effect_parameter